# Microsoft Access field formatting - adding unit type

Tags: forms, ms-access, format

I'm trying to display the unit type to some numeric fields in an access database.

So for instance a value of '15' in FieldA will display as '15 inch', and '26' in FieldB will be '26 mm'. Is this possible with field formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it? As long as your field is a some type of number field, it should work fine. Just set the format to #" inch" or #" mm".

Comment: I did exactly that; on the table itself rather than the form... For some reason I thought it would push the formatting through to the control. I'm dumb, thanks!